# React Query onSuccess in useMutation works oddly

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a component Task and I have 2 useMutation for that component, one for updating the status of the task and one for deleting, but the **queryClient.invalidateQueries()** in the onSuccess of the delete mutation just doesn't work, I have to reload the page to see the latest data from my database, but it works fine in the update mutation although they invalidate the same query. Somehow the onSuccess inside delete mutation wasn't triggered.
Here is the demo link: https://youtu.be/JXOCIVm4Z9s

```
// Task.jsx

<div onDoubleClick={() => handleDoubleClick(id, completed)}
            ....
            ....
                <button
                    className="text-sm bg-red-200 p-2 rounded-full"
                    onClick={() => handleDelete(id)}
                >
                    ️
                </button>
           ....
           ....
</div>
```

and this is the code for handleDelete and handleUpdate

```
//update

function handleDoubleClick(id, completed) {
        mutateUpdate({ id, completed });
    }

function updateTask({ id, completed }) {
        return axios.put(`http://localhost:4000/tasks/${id}`, {
            newName: "",
            completed: !completed,
        });
    }

const { mutate: mutateUpdate } = useMutation(updateTask, {
        onSuccess: () => {
            console.log('on success update');
            queryClient.invalidateQueries("tasks");
        },
    });
```

```
//delete

function handleDelete(id) {
        mutateDelete(id);
    }


function deleteTask(id) {
        return axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/tasks/${id}`);
}

const { mutate: mutateDelete } = useMutation(deleteTask, {
        onSuccess: () => {
            console.log("on success delete");
            queryClient.invalidateQueries("tasks");
        },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

After an hour of searching for bugs, it turns out that in my Express server, I forgot to return a response for this delete request, and useMutation kept waiting for the response so it didn't trigger the onSuccess method. Hope this will help other Node + React newbies like me